# What was the point of getting this item into the Quantum Tunnel?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

At the end of *Avengers: Endgame*  The Avengers are scrambling to get the Gauntlet to the Scott's van and into the Quantum Tunnel.  The goal seems to simply be getting the item to the Quantum Tunnel because we see Captain Marvel throw it towards the Quantum Tunnel, which Thanos stops by throwing his own sword, deflecting it at the last moment.

This seems very strange, because of course the goal was to properly return everything right back to where they came from.  In the end of course that is what they do.  However, throwing the item into the Quantum Tunnel seems completely pointless: it certainly wouldn't return anything to anywhere.  Worst case scenario you end up losing the thing in the Quantum Realm, making it impossible to return things as promised.  Perhaps they wanted to throw it in the Quantum Realm to prevent Thanos from getting it, but my own impression at the time was that the scramble for the van and the Quantum Tunnel was about returning things, not just temporarily hiding things from Thanos.

Am I missing something or is this just a plothole?

Comment: I think from the dialogue in which Tony was talking to Scott, they meant to get the stones back to each point in spacetime where they got them, not necessarily just chuck the gauntlet into the quantum realm

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Captain Marvel throws it towards the Quantum Tunnel, which Thanos stops by throwing his own sword, deflecting it at the last moment.

### No, she doesn't

> Am I missing something?

Yes..

Captain Marvel is **carrying** the Gauntlet to the van, presumably to either take the stones back herself or for Scott to do it (as he has a Time/Space GPS and she doesn't).

[image]

At this point, Thanos hurls his sword and destroys the van meaning that this avenue is now denied to the Avengers.

The blast from the destruction of the van/tunnel plows Captain Marvel into the rubble *at which point she loses her grip on the Gauntlet.*

Comment: Apparently I'm mis-remembering a detail there (regarding throwing the gauntlet versus simply having it knocked out of her hands by an explosion), but your statement about Scott and his Time/Space GPS is the bit that I was really missing.  I didn't see how getting the gauntlet to the tunnel at that specific moment would have allowed them to return everything, but I can accept a handwave that Scott would have taken the gauntlet, jumped in, and somehow been able to return everything.

Comment: It's not a "somehow". After all, he succeeded at the conclusion of the film.